# Test full hard drive on Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, check-disk

In the past I used to do (some times) full hard drive checks that tested not only the filesystem but the whole hard drive. It was a process that could take a while.

Recently I wanted to do that with Windows 10 but I didn't find that option. I think that it was only testing file system and that went impressively fast.
Am I missing of confusing something?
Where has this option gone?

Comment: Can you recall how you did it in the previous versions of Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll typically need to use 3rd party software to do a full hard drive test. Technically you could do a chkdsk /r from a command prompt to do a 5 stage chkdsk. This will test all the physical sectors of the drive in addition to the file system. Any bad sectors will then be marked as bad and won't be used again. But if you want to run a full diagnostic you'll need to use a 3rd party tool.

Which tool you use typically depends on your HDD manufacturer. For Seagate you'd use SeaTools (http://www.seagate.com/ca/en/support/downloads/seatools/) for Western Digital you'd use their Data Lifeguard software (http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en)

Most manufacturers have a free utility you can use to test your disk. There are also other paid utilities that can be used against any type of drive, no matter who manufactured it, such as QuickTech Premium (http://www.uxd.com/quicktech-premium.html)

Comment: Since yesterday I'm using HD Tune (Pro) do you thing that Data Lifeguard would be better for WD disks?

Comment: Just to answer my own question from previous comment, I have at list one hard disk that pass HD Tune Pro full scan but not Data Lifeguard's full scan.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe thinking of a SMART test; there's no native way to run one in Windows 10 ( I don't know if there was in previous windows versions)

However, there is plenty of free software to initiate the test for you, and display the results once it's done: [Crystal Disk Info](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) is one I've heard is good (no personal use myself as I run linux) but there are plenty more if you google for them.

Comment: It sounded more like something like "check for bad sectors". But I'll give check to Crystal Disk or alternatives when I am home and find some time. Thanks.

Comment: Smart info will highlight stuff such as bad sectors, and more. It'll give the number of reallocations as well.